# Capture the inserted data of oracle database to spring boot application

Tags: java, oracle, spring-boot

How to capture the record inserted into the oracle database (from external system) via spring boot application. (Kind of a listener)

If a new record is inserted into the oracle database, I need to get the inserted data as a DTO.

Help needed.

Thanks.

Comment: Aren't you the one inserting the record in the first place? Don't you already have a DTO with the data being inserted? --- Before we can advice on listeners, we'd need to know what technology you're using. JdbcTemplate? JPA? Spring Data? Which kind?

Comment: @Andreas data inserted to the oracle by an external system. My application is listening to database insertion.

Comment: How is it listening?

Comment: that's what I need to do